# How to know if my users come from Bing or google

Tags: html

Is there any way to find out where I is a user, that is to say I want to know whether users are more by bing or google adwords, is this what could be done with the header information , and in fact I could get but the problem this landing page that we have these extension .html and I can not change as google adwords are in .php

Comment: not sure how it work, but for the last point, you can change any .html to .php it will work assuming now a day all server read php.

Comment: Thank you, that I can not do because all ads that I have are in .html , I realizaria change to find out but my boss told me that we can not change , we have over 400 landing pages

Answer (score 0):

You can add google analytics or other web analytics service to your landing page, to track from which sources your users are coming.

Comment: Thanks for answering.

That would have but as I have enough Landings I want to know which converts better without waiting for a month is to say if one day go more users for ads adwords and not by bing bing ads taketh away